# PHP anomaly or bug?

Tags: php

We scratch our heads about how this result is achieved:

```
<?php
  $str = 'bg013.jpg';

  $a = $str != 0;
  $b = $str == 0;
  $c = $str === 0;

  var_dump($a);
  var_dump($b);
  var_dump($c);
?>
```

Results in:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Is there anything I missed? Suspicious, isn't it?

Comment: If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.  --> http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: imho, @pes502 might as well have posted that as an answer rather than a comment. this kind of behavior is inherent on weakly typed languages / constructions.

Comment: @TimothyGroote I don't want to post my comment as answer, because it's official text from PHP doc

Comment: @pes502 Haha, sorry. it just made a lot of sense when i read it. didn't check the PHP doc.

Comment: Not suspicious in the least, simply documented behaviour of loose typed comparisons

Comment: If I change the string to "3.jpg" it changes the result. That is - to me - not straight forward.